# Restrict click on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling

I am counting click time on circles.When this count was equal 3,then alert function show message with this content "You must avoid clicking" but when click on environment of circle this too counting. I want avoid counting from environment clicking.I want counting for clicking on circles. How Can I do this?

This is link of question and source code:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/testtest/bnsqvys3/1)

```
<div id="ways" style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;height:100%;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code already have the logic to detect clicks in/out of circles. Just put the logic of click amount inside that and you are done.

Comment: No, I want to write project and this is section of!

Comment: Please keep in mind that alerts can be turned off. What are you trying to accomplish? Would it make more sense to add a message on the screen and simply stop registering clicks?

Comment: I want just counting the clicked on circle not any area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you're asking, but you could move `turnclicking++` inside your `isPointInPath` test so that turnclicking would increase only when the user clicks inside a circle.

Comment: Yes, removing `turnclicking++` from where it is and putting it inside your `isPointInPath` will change `turnclicking` only when a circle is clicked and not when the user clicks outside a circle ;-)